# Difference between 「鳴く」and 「鳴る」?

Tags: word-choice

From what I've seen, 「鳴く」refers to a cry different from 「泣く」, ie crying out in fear/anger/frustration and not a baby crying. I've also seen connotations of animal sounds (barking, roaring).

I've also heard「鳴る」be translated as "ring", like the ringing of a bell.

Are these definitions accurate?

Comment: Was there some reason you doubted them?

Comment: I got these definitions from google translate. As my question states, I want to know how accurate they are.

Comment: Checking a Japanese-English dictionary would be more reliable than google translate, though there doesn't seem to be anything like some of the egregious mistakes it can sometimes make here. If you do that and still have questions, then we could address those.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, 鳴く is used for sounds from living things, 鳥が鳴く、犬が鳴く
as 鳴る is used for sounds from non-living things like 電話が鳴る.

There are exceptions, such as when using metaphorical expressions, but basically, the above usage is fine.